# Commit the changes in the child dir in a straight way

Tags: git

When I am working on the subdirectory of a git-repo, I should change dir to the parent to issue commands like

```
$ cd ..; git add .; git commit -m "2018-11-02 17:58:09" ; cd -
[master 0984351] 2018-11-02 17:58:09
 12 files changed, 558 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-)
```

Change to parent dir, commit changes and change back

How could I commit directly under the child directory?

Answer (score 1):

Not `git commit` requires that you are at the top of the repo but your `git add .`. So this should work:

```
git add ..; git commit -m "whatever"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can commit from a subdirectory. The path when using `git add` is relative to the current directory.

So if you want to `add` everything from your current directory and the parent one, use `git add ..` instead of `git add .`